# Trying to show score on simple HTML and JavaScript Trivia game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Completely new to Javascript and jQuery. I'm building this Trivia quiz with HTML, CSS and Javascript/jQuery and have run into issues.

Here's my complete code - https://jsfiddle.net/CeeSt/8wLj1pk2/ for reference.

Here's a snippet of my HTML and JS -

```
<div class="question">Question1?
  <ul class="answers">
    <li><label><input name="Question0" id="correct" type="checkbox"> Answer1</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="Question0" id="wrong" type="checkbox"> Answer2</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="Question0" id="wrong" type="checkbox"> Answer3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS file -

```
var score = 0;

function Results() {
  if (document.getElementById("correct").checked === true) score++;
  else (alert("Incorrect!"));

}
```

Specifically, I am trying to have the score total displayed in some fashion and am at a loss. I know it's recognizing the 'correct' answer, but showing this as the quiz progresses is what I am struggling with. I know there is likely a better way to do this in pure JavaScript, but if there is any way to salvage this method, please help! Thank you!!

Comment: You should be using `radio` buttons I guess!

Comment: I wondered if the use of selection made a difference...

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate `id="wrong"`, IDs should be unique. Use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: @Barmar would it be better to have `value="uniquethinghere"`?

Comment: @user6442393, Can you have both `correct` and `wrong` option selected ?

Comment: @Rayon I ran through it and it seems after question1, even if the 'correct' is selected, everything is incorrect, it's a mess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with using radio buttons and value. You can easily calculate the score like so:

```
var score = $('input:checked[value=correct]').length
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLxr3ooq/

Note: If you change "value" to "id" it still works... but you should avoid having duplicate IDs

Comment: Ah, yes, so now it says 'Results' is undefined...but I don't even need that!! That helps immensely!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this using the id property.  You can however use the value property.

You'd then need to modify the score field.  I don't think I saw anywhere where you did that.

Comment: _"You can't really do this using the id"_ ? Are you sure ?

Comment: I think I originally had the value property, but for some reason was having issues with Javascript recognizing the 'answers'...

Comment: You should run into problems given that id is supposed to be unique to each element.  The value attribute of the input tag can though.

Comment: You would have to tell javascript what to get the value of.  I would also suggest using a radio button as it will make sure you can only select 1 answer.  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert these to radio buttons and then evaluate the selected radio button to check whether it is correct:

```
<div class="question">Question1?
  <ul class="answers">
    <li><label><input name="Question0" value="correct" type="radio"> Answer1</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="Question0" value="wrong" type="radio"> Answer2</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="Question0" value="wrong" type="radio"> Answer3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and your JS would look something like:

```
var score = 0;

function Results() {
  if ($("input[name=Question0]:checked").val() == "correct") {
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are assigning the same ID to more than one element, which is not allowed. Instead, you can assign them classes. So in your case, assign a class *wrong* and a class *correct* to your respective elements. Then, in your JavaScript, try the following

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("correct");
```

This will grab all the elements with the class *correct* and return them in an array.

Comment: I can see this working, I haven't tried it yet, I'll test it out...thank you!

Comment: I removed the part about the score. I haven't really checked to see how you are determining the score but I still think this should help :)